# Plotting with random number of x values

Tags: python

I want to plot for a particular set of x and y values.

```
y_0= abs(z-125) ##  z-known so it's not a problem
x_0= abs(z-125)-x ##  x- this is unknown

plt.plot(x_0,y_0)
plt.title("y_values vs x_values")
plt.xlabel("x_values")
plt.ylabel("y_values")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

My problem is that I get an error:
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

How can I vary x (by 0.001 increment) so that x_0 and y_0 will have the same dimension and I would be able to plot it?

Note: x and z are both arrays

For example

```
y_0= abs(z-125) 
>>print y_0
[ 13.47 35.937 1124. ..., 19.543 30.049 1124. ]

x_0= abs(z-125) -0.001
>>print x_0   
[   13.469    35.936  1123.999 ...,    19.542    30.048  1123.999]

x_1= abs(z-125) -0.002
>>print x_1
[   13.468    35.935  1123.998 ...,    19.541    30.047  1123.998]
```

as you can see 0.001 and 0.002 above is part of x which is an array. I want to plot y_0 vs x_0 (x_1.. x_2... x_3) but doing it one by one is not practical

Comment: [`numpy.linspace`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

Comment: @Ffisegydd: z is given (an array), but x is unknown (the one I will set).

Comment: @Ffisegydd: it is an array

Comment: Your problem is not with your plotting, your problem is whatever you're doing with `x` and you are not showing any of your details. As such it is unclear what you're asking. Voting to close.

Comment: @Ffisegydd:

Let' say z= 1000
so, y_0= abs(1000-125)= 875

Let's say x= 1
so, x_0= abs(1000-125)-x = 875-1 =874

so my first point is (874,875)

z is an array so there are lots of values (that is known)
x is an array which is I want to set so x has the same number of elements as z

Everything clear now or you need further explanation? I just want help since I'm new in programming.

Comment: No it's not clear, you've not explained where x comes from, how it's meant to be transformed to have the same shape as z, or anything. I'm sorry but as you said you're new to programming and you need to read some tutorials on how numpy and matplotlib works because at the moment you are not able to articulate what you want.

Comment: @Ffisegydd I edited my question. Is it clear now or you need further elaboration?